# jquery: comboBox.trigger(´chosen:update´) documentation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, combobox

`comboBox.trigger(´chosen:updated´)` what does this do in Jquery?

Anyone can give an example?

I dont see any effect or utility.
I really search over 20 links over google and I cannot find the documentation.

---- correcions ----

´chosen:update´ to ´chosen:updated´

Answer (score 0):

> `comboBox.trigger(´chosen:update´)`

---

```
comboBox
```

You will have a variable that points to a jquery collection containing a `select`, likely setup using

```
let comboBox = $("#mySelect");
```

---

```
.trigger
```

Raises the named event

---

```
'chosen:update'
```

the name of the event to raise.

In this case, the event is *namespaced*, this just allows it to be specifically  looked for in the `chosen` namespace.  It could also be `.trigger("updated")` and chosen2 will likely pick it up - this stop other code such as `.on("update"..` from triggering.

It also appears to be a typo as the event (depending on the version of chosen2) should be `updated`.

---

All together, you call this code when you change the value of the underlying `select`, eg:

```
var comboBox = $("#mySelect");
comboBox.val("newValue");
comboBox.trigger(´chosen:update´)
```

when your `select` has been converted to a select2 combo box.  Without which, the select2 UI would not be updated to match the new value.

---

**NB:** The event to trigger appears to change with each version of select2, it could be one of:

```
comboBox.trigger('chosen:updated');
comboBox.trigger('change');
```

Comment: Yes it was a typo, i´ve corrected it, thanks for the answer @freedomn-m

Comment: Thanks again, but y put here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qh5ok7a4/

and it does nothing because the value in combobox is refreshed. I was asking for the semantic of chosen:updated